# Identification of oscillatory motion

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, definition, oscillators

How to check if a motion is oscillatory or not? 
What is the condition for an oscillatory motion?

Answer (score 2):

- An oscillatory motion is a periodic motion. A function representing oscillatory motion must be periodic too. There exists a $T > 0$ such that $\forall t$
  $$f(t+T) = f(t)$$
- Simple harmonic motion is a mathematical model for describing oscillations. Here, the restoring force $F$ is directly proportional to displacement $x$ and acts in the direction opposite to that of displacement.

$$F \propto -x \implies F = -kx$$ for some constant $k$.

- Writing $F = m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx$ and solving it, you could represent the motion as $x = c_1 \cos(\omega t) + c_2 \sin(\omega t)$ or equivalently $x = A \cos(\omega t + \phi)$. Note that it is periodic.

Comment: The question is not about simple harmonic motion. The second bullets are irrelevant.

Comment: @alephzero, I meant SHM as a model to further give a structure to oscillatory behaviors. I understand only the first point is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The oscillatory motion simply means that the movement repeats in a cycle. I.e. the graph of the position vs. time is some sort of repeating wave.

Now if you're talking about *simple harmonic motion*, then the characteristics are a little more involved. In SHM, the following condition must be met:

$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} =-kx$

This condition can be interpreted in a number of ways. Because $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$ is proportional to the force, you can say that SHM results from a system that experiences a force at all times proportional and opposite to the position. If you were to solve this equation, you would find that the result is some function $y=A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$.

In a practical sense, SHM can usually be tested by asking "Is the acceleration negatively proportional to the position?"

Answer (score 0):

Oscillatory motion always has a defined non-zero time period.

Comment: This answer is a bit short and doesn't answer the question fully